# How to obtain opposite colour

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, background-color

I have a custom coloured background that the user can choose, this however means when they change the colour, the label is invisible because it is the same as the background and I do not want this. The code I have is: `opacityLabel.textColor = bgView.backgroundColor;` In this bit of code the colour is the same at the start but doesn't change when I adjust the background colour, I also need the colour to continually change with the background colour, I was wondering what I could replace with "=" to make the label do the opposite colour. I can't do "!=" because that means is not equal to rather than **opposite**! If you can't do it this way could you provide me with a way of doing it?

Comment: You shouldn't be aiming for an 'opposite color', since it does not exist.
What you want is a color that is still readable given a background color, so contrast is more important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you'll need to do is calculate the opposite colour to the `backgroundColor`, and then assign it to the `textColor` property.

To do this you'll need to use the `getRed:green:blue:alpha:` method on `backgroundColor`. This will give you values between 0.0 and 1.0 for each component of your colour.
Then use the `UIColor` class method `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` to create a new `UIColor`, but use (1.0 - component value) for each of the components.

Then finally assign your new colour to `opacityLabel.textColor`